# Merging differently sized pandas dataframes based on common column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with datetime index from 2006-01-19 to 2007-01-25 like this:

```
         YEAR   DOY  temperature
datetime                             
2016-01-19  2016.0    NaN
2016-01-20  2016.0    NaN
2016-01-21  2016.0    NaN
2016-01-22  2016.0    NaN
2016-01-23  2016.0    NaN
.....
2017-01-24  2017.0    NaN
```

All `temperature` values in the dataframe above are NaNs.

I want to join another dataframe containing `temperature` values for each day of the year (366 in all):

```
   YEAR  DOY  temperature 
0  2013    1         3.66 
1  2013    2         4.00 
2  2013    3         1.38 
3  2013    4        -0.44 
.....
4  2013    366       0.22
```

I want to join these dataframes based on the `DOY` column so that e.g. day 22 of the first dataframe has `temperature` value that is obtained for day 22 from the second dataframe. I tried this:

```
df_a.merge(df_b, on='DOY', suffixes=('_x', ''))
```

However, this does not work. How do I fix it?

Comment: I don't actually see a day of year column in the first df. Maybe that's your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use the full syntax:

```
merged = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, how='left', left_on='DOY', right_on='DOY', suffixes=('_x', ''))
```

This way of merging is clearer to me personally.

You can look at the [documentation on merging](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) to find out more about merging.